# WebSocket connection failed with Render.com

Tags: reactjs, websocket, socket.io, backend, render.com

I tried to deploy my backend to render.com after failing on vercel.
Everything seems to work fine except when I attempted to connect to websocket with Socket.io for my chat interface.

I'm not really that advanced with deploying so I tried to read some answers and all but nothing seems to work for me .
Here's the code server for my app :

```
require("dotenv").config();
const PORT = process.env.PORT;
const IO_PORT = process.env.IO_PORT;
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const dbConnect = require("./config/db");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const corsOptions = require("./config/corsOptions");
const verifyJWT = require("./api/middleware/verifyJWT");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const credentials = require("./api/middleware/credentials");
const io = require("socket.io")(IO_PORT, {
  cors: {
    origins: "*:*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
  }
});

io.use((socket, next) => {
  const apptId = socket.handshake.auth.apptId;
  if (!apptId) {
    return next(new Error("Invalid appointment"));
  }
  socket.apptId = apptId;
  next();
});

// IO Connection
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(`Client ${socket.id} connected to room ${socket.apptId}`);
  socket.join(socket.apptId);
  socket.on("add-note", (updatedNotes, id) => {
    if (id) {
      socket.to(id).emit("add-note", updatedNotes);
    }
  });
  socket.on("delete-note", (updatedNotes, id) => {
    if (id) {
      socket.to(id).emit("delete-note", updatedNotes);
    }
  });
  socket.on("send-message", (messageObj, id) => {
    if (id) {
      socket.to(id).emit("send-message", messageObj);
    }
  });
});
```

IO_PORT is set to 3000.

Here's how I connect to socket io in the front end

socket.js

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const URL = "wss://instadoc-api.onrender.com";

export const socket = io(URL, {
  autoConnect: false,
  transports: ["websocket"]
});
```

and I'm getting this error

```
index-327b36e2.js:69 WebSocket connection to 'wss://instadoc-api.onrender.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed: 
doOpen  @   index-327b36e2.js:69
open    @   index-327b36e2.js:69
open    @   index-327b36e2.js:69
kn  @   index-327b36e2.js:69
open    @   index-327b36e2.js:69
(anonymous) @   index-327b36e2.js:69
```

I couldn't figure it out, how can I fix this on render.com?